# laravel websocket client not work no error

Tags: laravel, websocket

Im trying websocket from this package
https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/

but when test from 
http://localhost:8000/laravel-websockets 
send event button its fire event in console

but client console not log and no error

I send event please check below screenshot
[image]

The data reveived from socket server console
[image]

that is my client code for test
but that not log in chrome console.
[image]

this is config/broadcast.php

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

thanks you.

Comment: kindly post `websockets.php` config and `bootstrap.js` where you initialize laravel echo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the full path to your laravel event in the event creator. Try `App\Event\WebSocketDemoEvent` instead of `WebSocketDemoEvent`.

Initialize laravel echo if you haven't already and then listen to your channel with -

```js
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '{{env('PUSHER_APP_KEY')}}',
    cluster: '',
    encrypted: false,
    wsPort: '{{env('PUSHER_APP_PORT')}}'
});

window.Echo.channel('DemoChannel').listen('WebSocketDemoEvent', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
}
```